# Why Python3 Popen cannot use wildcards to copy files

Tags: python-3.x

While trying to copy a set of files from 1 directory to another, I have some code as

```
>>> cpCmd = ["cp", blogdir + "/*.log", thisdir+"/."]
>>> cpCmd
['cp', '/Volumes/Data/abcd/boards/*.log', './.']
>>> cProc = subprocess.Popen(cpCmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> (cOut, cErr) = cProc.communicate()
>>> cExitCode = cProc.wait()
>>> cExitCode
1
>>> print(cErr.decode('ascii').rstrip())
cp: /Volumes/Data/abcd/aging_logs/boards/*.log: No such file or directory
```

However, when the log files are on a remote host and I use

```
scp user@host:dir_path/*.log local_dir
```

It works just fine. Is there is difference between how python3 interacts with the shell in the 2 cases? This is on MacOS 10.13.2. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Python example, no shell is involved: Python executes `cp` directly. Globs are only expanded by the shell, so `cp` receives the literal argument `/Volumes/Data/abcd/aging_logs/boards/*.log` and no file with that name exists.

In the `scp` case, the `*` is being passed literally to `scp` in the same way, but `scp` is expanding the glob on the remote system. This is a feature of `scp`.

You can use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html) module to expand the glob and pass the full list of filenames to `cp`. (You could also use `Popen`'s `shell=True` argument, but please heed the [security considerations in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations).)

Comment: Thank you. I did not want to use shell=True for security as you pointed out, and ended up in a [f for f in listdir(dirname) if isfile(join(dname,f))] kind of structure, basically looping for all the files in the dir.